# A tag [speech-recognation] deveria ser [reconhecimento-de-voz]?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tag-específica

A tag [speech-recognation](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognation) está com a grafia em inglês errada. O correto seria [speech-recognition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/speech-recognition), se continuasse em inglês.

Minha proposta é que a tag seja renomeada para [reconhecimento-de-voz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reconhecimento-de-voz). O que acham?

Comment: Dado que não se trata de um nome comercial, sou a favor de usar o termo em português.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concordo. Renomeado. ..........

Comment: O sinônimo ainda ficou com grafia em inglês errada. Isso é proposital?

Comment: Eu não sei se pode apagar simplesmente, pelo menos não tem como de maneira óbvia. Eu só renomeei o que existia. Se for o caso ter um sinônimo escrito certo teria que ter uma *tag* escrita certa para colocar sinônimo.

Comment: Eu pensei que talvez pudesse criar o sinônimo com grafia correta e remover o sinônimo com grafia incorreta. Mas eu com certeza sei menos do que você como essa parte funciona. Só perguntei mesmo porque pensei que poderia ter passado despercebido.