# A tag [lambda-expressions] deveria ser [expressões-lambda]?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tag-específica

A tag [lambda-expressions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda-expressions) poderia ser renomeada para [expressões-lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express%c3%b5es-lambda). Acredito que tenha a mesma expressividade e é melhor localizada.

O que acham da sugestão?

Comment: Concordo pelo mesmo motivo que transformou [*"speech recognition"* em *"reconhecimento de voz"*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6457/1658).

Comment: E manter [tag:lambda-expressions] como sinônimo. Por mim de acordo.

Comment: E aí? Alguém pode sugerir o sinônimo?

Comment: Feito: [tag:expressões-lambda]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O @Math diria: Está feito! [expressões-lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express%c3%b5es-lambda). Agora [lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) e [lambda-expressions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda-expressions) são sinônimos.

---

Answer (score -1):

Eu sei que o caso já foi resolvido, mas em questão de facilitar para o usuário, apenas [lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda) ao invés de [expressões-lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express%c3%b5es-lambda) não seria melhor?

Digo isto para facilitar digitar, creio que proporcionar uma melhor experiencia para os usuários.

Se concordarem upvote, caso contrário downvote aqui por favor.

Comment: Se você for elaborar uma pergunta e digitar [tag:lambda] já vai relacionar com [tag:expressões-lambda].

Comment: @Stormwind compreendo isto, pensando bem pode ser útil assim mesmo, ainda sim penso que na hora do autocomplete a sensação não é tão agradável. Mas talvez seja apenas um sensação particular.